# AWK replace entry from one column if entry from another column contains a match

Tags: linux, awk, substr

I am trying to use awk to replace all entries in column 11 with "0.400" when the third column contains the string "AAA". My input looks as follows:

```
ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638  44.587  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.232  A
ATOM      2  BB  ABC     1      59.675  45.544  36.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM      3  CCC ABC     1      59.127 -45.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM      4  DD  ABC     1      59.791  44.664  34.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM      5  EEE ABC     1      60.801  44.256  35.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
.
.
.
ATOM  14996  AAA ABC     1      80.638  44.387  76.897  0.00  0.00     0.232  A
ATOM  14997  BB  ABC     1      19.675 -25.544  66.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM  14998  CCC ABC     1      89.127  75.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM  14999  DD  ABC     1     -29.791  34.664 -54.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM  15000  EEE ABC     1      90.801  74.256  25.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
```

I am using `awk '$3 == "AAA" {$11= 0.400}1' file` which achieves this successfully, however the formatting of my file is messed up. The first five lines of the output are:

```
ATOM 1 AAA ABC 1 -60.638 44.587 36.897 0.00 0.00 0.4 A
ATOM      2  BB  ABC     1      59.675  45.544  36.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM      3  CCC ABC     1      59.127 -45.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM      4  DD  ABC     1      59.791  44.664  34.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM      5  EEE ABC     1      60.801  44.256  35.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
```

Is there a way I could achieve this while preserving the formatting of the file? I believe I could use sprintf and substr with awk, and something like "%8.3f" to specify the number of zeroes after the decimal point for 0.400, however, I am not familiar with the syntax. I would like my output to look as follows:

```
ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638  44.587  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.400  A
ATOM      2  BB  ABC     1      59.675  45.544  36.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM      3  CCC ABC     1      59.127 -45.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM      4  DD  ABC     1      59.791  44.664  34.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM      5  EEE ABC     1      60.801  44.256  35.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
```

Thank you in advance for the guidance!

Comment: have you tried a web search on `awk maintain spacing`; if you've got `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) you're likely to find the `FPAT` and/or 4-arg`split()` to be of benefit; additional tweaks may be necessary to address alignment if replacing a negative number with a positive number, and vice versa (ie, addressing the offset for the `-`)

Comment: @jared_mamrot unfortunately the file is not tab delimited! Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

The formatting can be preserved by making a string substitution *of the same length* for field 11 in field 0:

```
awk '$3=="AAA"{gsub($11,"0.400", $0)} 1' file
```

output:

```
ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638  44.587  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.400  A
ATOM      2  BB  ABC     1      59.675  45.544  36.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM      3  CCC ABC     1      59.127 -45.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM      4  DD  ABC     1      59.791  44.664  34.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM      5  EEE ABC     1      60.801  44.256  35.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
```

To account for the possibility that the digits of field 11 appear elsewhere, white space can be used (assuming field  11 always has x.xxx format and no other column does, as in  the example)

```
awk '$3=="AAA"{gsub(" "$11" "," 0.400 ", $0)} 1' file
```

Comment: @markp-fuso good point, work around added, assuming format given.

Comment: @DavePritlove : your work around didn't work : :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: :  input ::: `ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638   0.232  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.232  A` 
::: output ::: `ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638   0.400  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.400  A`

Comment: You can tighten it up a bit by checking the return for `gsub()` and if greater than `1` loop over the fields and find and count the prior occurrences and save and decorate any prior occurrences with some non-used char like `"!!!!"` (whatever) and then after decorating prior occurrences, make the substitution for `$11` and then undecorate (reverse the decorations with the original content). So long as this doesn't occur every other record, it wouldn't impact efficiency that bad.

Answer (score 1):

i purposely modified `row 1` `column 7` to `0.232`  to make sure only `$11` is replaced :

> ```
> mawk '11 < NF || $_ = sprintf("%.*s0.400 %2s", match($_,
>                         "[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+$")-!_, $_, $NF)' \
>                     FS='^[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+AAA[ \t]|[ \t]+'
> ```

```
ATOM      1  AAA ABC     1     -60.638   0.232  36.897  0.00  0.00     0.400  A
ATOM      2  BB  ABC     1      59.675  45.544  36.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM      3  CCC ABC     1      59.127 -45.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM      4  DD  ABC     1      59.791  44.664  34.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM      5  EEE ABC     1      60.801  44.256  35.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
ATOM  14996  AAA ABC     1      80.638  44.387  76.897  0.00  0.00     0.400  A
ATOM  14997  BB  ABC     1      19.675 -25.544  66.863  0.00  0.00    -0.252 BB
ATOM  14998  CCC ABC     1      89.127  75.567  35.637  0.00  0.00     0.145  C
ATOM  14999  DD  ABC     1     -29.791  34.664 -54.873  0.00  0.00     0.055  D
ATOM  15000  EEE ABC     1      90.801  74.256  25.627  0.00  0.00    -0.245  E
```

if you're willing to take the leap of faith and assume all blanks are spaces and no tabs, then it's a lot simpler :

> ```
> gawk '11<NF || $_ = sprintf("%.*s0.400 %2s", match($_, 
>                               "[^ ]+ +[^ ]+$")-!_, $_, 
>                     $NF)' FS='^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +AAA | +'
> ```